# Quick way to solve a modular equation

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I have the following equation:

```
In [1505]: (327*327*108)%1009                                                                                                                                 
Out[1505]: 327
```

Only 108 (as far as i know( will return 327. So the equation is:

```
(327*327*x)%1009 = 327.  What is the quickest way to solve for this step by step.
```

I can solve this using this formula:

```
In [1508]: fastlinearcongruencex2(327,1,1009, withstats=True)                                                                                                 
quotient = 0, old_r = 327, r = 1009, old_s = 1, s = 0
quotient = 0, old_r = 1009, r = 327, old_s = 0, s = 1
quotient = 3, old_r = 327, r = 28, old_s = 1, s = -3
quotient = 11, old_r = 28, r = 19, old_s = -3, s = 34
quotient = 1, old_r = 19, r = 9, old_s = 34, s = -37
quotient = 2, old_r = 9, r = 1, old_s = -37, s = 108
quotient = 9, old_r = 1, r = 0, old_s = 108, s = -1009
```

but it seems there is a much simpler answer, is there?

Comment: 1) Note that $\gcd(327,1009)=1$ thus cancel by $327$: $327x\equiv 1\pmod{1009}$, $\quad$ 2) so $x=327^{-1}$ and this can be done using [Extended Equclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm): $108\cdot 327-35\cdot 1009=1$ so $108\cdot 327\equiv 1\pmod{1009}$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin thank you , can you tell me how you derived the number 35? The equation i have above is egcd but i don't see 35 in any of the steps, so i'm wondering how you got to that answer, which is the answer i want. thanks again.

Comment: From the extended Euclidean algorithm for $\gcd(327,1009)$.

Comment: [here](https://tio.run/##bZFBTsMwEEX3nOJTNgkyakIXpZW64SJVG08aS62d2hOg3IhzcLDg2MKtEbOwrD9v/sxo@gt3Ri9eejuOklrQB5OWJLeHRhY7gX25voOPwhzl1grYEhvExFV3Ai7otUB1o7MAB70SqKMenvdOHQkW9xtU0X6K82BYkWZfEJphPodN2XwA/4nM07Xs0edyPM3lIu5y3P3B07gccc5xvtngwQzcD4zZ6/fXp/@jMdS2qplQt56J1D/4xEJLPFj9Xya5HSztmNxkdzoZDanelDN2Mgzr5vTvbA77C7gj@JuF3jztPfZWaS6ygy6el6KuqlVZjj8) is the port of the code from the section [Pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Pseudocode) from the link above. You can check it outputs $(108,-35)$. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I implemented both pseudocodes at the wikipedia page and couldn't come up with the answer of 35. Would you be so kind to answer the question which i would give you credit for, showing the step that results in 35? Thank you so much for you consideration

Comment: Actually, it looks like i'm getting the bezout_t as -35, bezout_t = -35
Bézout coefficients: (108, -35) .   I think i might have it, but if your getting the answer before going through the entire formula, let me know.

Comment: The $35$ isn't as important as the $108$.  The ext euc alg gives us that $108*327 = 1 + 1009K$ for some $K$ and solving $K=\frac {108*327-1}{1009} =35$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\gcd(327,1009)= 1$ so there is an $h$ so that $327*h \equiv 1 \pmod{1009}$ so if $327*327*x \equiv 327 \pmod{1009}$ then

$327x \equiv h*327*327*x \equiv h* 327 \equiv 1\pmod {1009}$ and so

$x \equiv h*327x \equiv h*1 \equiv h\pmod{1009}$.

So I have to find out what $h$ is.

$3*327 = 981 \equiv -28\pmod {1009}$

$327 = 28*12-9$ so

$327\equiv (-3*327)*12 -9\pmod {1009}$

$37*327 \equiv - 9\pmod{1009}$

$28 = 3*9 + 1$

$-3*327 \equiv 3*(-37*327) + 1\pmod{1009}$

$108*327 \equiv 1 \pmod {1009}$

So $h \equiv 108$ and $x \equiv 108 \pmod{1009}$.

=====

And indeed $108*327*327=35316*327 = (1009*35 +1)*327 = 1009*(35*327) + 327$.

Comment: Ok, i have a lot to learn, like how you got this: 327=28∗12−9   If you can point me to a resource or wikipedia page on how you got that, that would be awesome. I'm learning and this is very useful, this solution seems faster than a straight egcd

Comment: I just ordered 
Number Theory (Dover Books on Mathematics) and
Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective    Can you think of  any other books or we resourced that will help me reduce numbers in the manner you do? thanks!